# Magnolia CMS & JWPlayer integration for video player with mutiple video formats to be run

Tags: browser, video, jwplayer, magnolia

I am working on Magnolia CMS for creating templates & using JWBox & JWPlayer for video player implementation on running multiple video formats like mp4, webm, ogg & importantly flash fallback.

I have a situation now that it doesnt work on some of the browsers like Mozilla & Opera but if i run this on normal html file the code works

The Code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>All</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jwbox.css" media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jwbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="video.js"></script>




</head>
<body>
<div class="jwbox" style="margin-bottom:-50px">
<img class="jwboxPosterImg" src="image.jpg"/>
<img class="jwboxPlayButton" alt="Play" width="50" style="position:relative;left:-155px;top:-75px;cursor:pointer;opacity:0.5;filter:alpha(opacity=50)" title="Click to play" src="play_button.png"/>
<div class="jwbox_hidden">
<div  class="jwbox_content">
    <video id="" width="365" height="266" controls="controls" poster="image.jpg">
    <source src="testvid.ogv" type="video/ogv" />
    <source src="testvid.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="testvid.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640" height="480" wmode="transparent" data="player.swf?file=testvid.mp4&autostart=true&image=image.jpg">
    <param name="movie" value="player.swf?file=testvid.mp4&autostart=true&image=image.jpg"/>
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    </object>

    </video>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <br>
 <div class="jwbox" style="margin-bottom:-50px">
<img class="jwboxPosterImg" src="image.jpg"/>
<img class="jwboxPlayButton" alt="Play" width="50" style="z-index:1003;position:relative;left:-155px;top:-75px;cursor:pointer;opacity:0.5;filter:alpha(opacity=50)" title="Click to play" src="play_button.png"/>
<div class="jwbox_hidden">
<div  class="jwbox_content">
    <video id="" width="365" height="266" controls="controls" poster="image.jpg">
    <source src="testvid.ogv" type="video/ogv" />
    <source src="testvid.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="testvid.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640" height="480" wmode="transparent" data="player.swf?file=testvid.mp4&autostart=true&image=image.jpg">
    <param name="movie" value="player.swf?file=testvid.mp4&autostart=true&image=image.jpg"/>
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />

    </object>
    <p>Your browser does not support the video tag. If want you can put fallback method instead of this line....</p>
    </video>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>

 </body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var d = $('video');
for(i=0;i<d.length;i++){
    d[i].id="video_"+i;
}
setTimeout( function() {
    var ff = $('video');
    for(j=0;j<2;j++){
        jwplayer(ff[j].id).setup({
            height: 480, 
            width: 640, 
            autostart:true,
            modes: [ 
            { type: "html5" }, 
            { type: "flash", src: "player.swf" }, 
            { type: "download" } 
            ] 
        }); 
    }
}, 500 );
</script>

 </html>
```

the Exception thrown by Magnolia when run on Mozilla/Opera is(which works on IE/Chrome/Safari):

2011-09-08 13:46:15,460 ERROR info.magnolia.module.dms.DMSDownloadServlet       : error during download

```
ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:358)

        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:323)

        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:381)

        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:370)

        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:89)

        at info.magnolia.module.dms.DMSDownloadServlet.sendUnCompressed(DMSDownloadServlet.java:123)

        at info.magnolia.module.dms.DMSDownloadServlet.handleResourceRequest(DMSDownloadServlet.java:108)

        at info.magnolia.module.dms.DMSDownloadServlet.process(DMSDownloadServlet.java:184)

        at info.magnolia.module.dms.DMSDownloadServlet.doGet(DMSDownloadServlet.java:74)

        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)

        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.ServletDispatchingFilter.doFilter(ServletDispatchingFilter.java:119)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:84)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:84)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:84)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:84)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:84)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:84)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:84)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:66)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.VirtualUriFilter.doFilter(VirtualUriFilter.java:69)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)

        at info.magnolia.module.cache.executor.Bypass.processCacheRequest(Bypass.java:57)

        at info.magnolia.module.cache.filter.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:147)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:60)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)

        at info.magnolia.cms.i18n.I18nContentSupportFilter.doFilter(I18nContentSupportFilter.java:75)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)

        at info.magnolia.module.extendedtemplatingkit.filters.MultiSiteFilter.doFilter(MultiSiteFilter.java:94)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:84)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:84)

        at info.magnolia.cms.security.BaseSecurityFilter.doFilter(BaseSecurityFilter.java:64)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)

        at info.magnolia.cms.security.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:88)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:60)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)

        at info.magnolia.cms.security.auth.login.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:77)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)

        at info.magnolia.enterprise.registration.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:51)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:84)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.CosMultipartRequestFilter.doFilter(CosMultipartRequestFilter.java:86)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:60)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.ContentTypeFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeFilter.java:102)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:120)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:66)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:88)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.doFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:105)

        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.doFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:216)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)

        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)

        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)

        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)

        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)

        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)

        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)

        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)

        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)

        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:741)

        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:432)

        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:347)

       at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:765)

        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityOutputFilter.doWrite(IdentityOutputFilter.java:118)

        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:574)

        at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:560)

        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:353)

        ... 76 more
```

Get me a solution...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

This question is two years old and at the time the DMSDownloadServlet wasn't abled to deliver contents with "byte range support" (see [MAGNOLIA-3855](http://jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/MAGNOLIA-3855)). I can remember having the exact same issue.

Magnolia now has a filter in the filter chain named "range" `info.magnolia.cms.filters.RangeSupportFilter` and this should solve these issues.

Answer (score 0):

The error appears to indicate that JWPlayer is resetting the connection when Magnolia's DMS is trying to serve content to it. I'm not sure why that would be, unless it is perhaps expecting to be able to do a [HTTP Partial Get](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.3) and is cranky that Magnolia's DMS download servlet isn't providing that functionality.

If it were me, I might try putting [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or something similar on the connection between server and client to see what's happening differently with the different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The exception you see in the logs is the result of the client closing the connection to the server, or a network device terminating the connection (like a cranky firewall limiting throughput or more likely the lifespan of connections). An upstream proxying web server can also be the problem. In either case I would diagnose the problem first on the client, then firewalls before Magnolia itself.

The exception is common in server logs since it's thrown when a browser aborts the connection, for instance when the user clicks the stop button in the browser.